# Box-shadow Inset fill leaving unfilled edges?

Tags: html, css

I am using a css transition to fill my buttons during hover using box-shadow inset.

I am also using the transition to alter border-radius of the button during hover.

When I hover, the transition happens, but I am left with a thin unfilled curved line on each inner-corner of the button.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="upSwipe">Up Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="downSwipe">Down Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="leftSwipe">Left Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="rightSwipe">Right Swipe</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  margin: 20px;
  
  background: none;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 orange;
  
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#upSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -7em 0 orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  
  margin: 20px;
  
  background: none;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
  
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 orange;
  
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#upSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -7em 0 orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: just remove `border-radius` property from your hover css
or just decrease `border-radius` to `20px` as per your button radius

Comment: You can set `border:none` to the all `:hover` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. You need to change the `border-radius` from button.
> 2. Remove the `border-radius` on hover.

removing `border-radius` on hover alone will not fix the issue, you can either increase the `border` size of button or decrease the `border-radius` of the button.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#upSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -7em 0 orange;
  color: black;
}

#downSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 7em 0 orange;
  color: black;
}

#leftSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 7em 0 0 orange;
  color: black;
}

#rightSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset -7em 0 0 orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="upSwipe">Up Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="downSwipe">Down Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="leftSwipe">Left Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="rightSwipe">Right Swipe</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `border:none` to the all `:hover` classes, you can keep origin the shape of the button (the one with inner radius, not a rectangle).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: orange;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 orange;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#upSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -7em 0 orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
}

#downSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 7em 0 orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
}

#leftSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 7em 0 0 orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
}

#rightSwipe:hover {
  box-shadow: inset -7em 0 0 orange;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="upSwipe">Up Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="downSwipe">Down Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="leftSwipe">Left Swipe</button>
  <button type="button" id="rightSwipe">Right Swipe</button>
</div>
```